# Why new elements don't add in list?

Tags: c#, list, winforms, sudoku

I have a C# WinForms sudoku game. Form1 is the main menu form and Form2 is the game form. I create lists for player name and score. I am trying to make it work such that after a win, the player's score is added in the list and then it will be added in Form1.listBox1. But new player scores don't add in the list and I don't understand why.

This is Form1 code:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form2 frm2;
    public Form1 frm1;
    
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm2.players.Add(textBox1.Text);

        textBox1.Text = "";
        frm2.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.frm1 = this;     
    }
```

This is reduced Form2 code:

```cs
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form1 frm1;
    int s;
    public List<string> players = new List<string>(5);
    public List<int> score = new List<int>(5) ;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm1 = new Form1();
        frm1.frm2 = this;
        s = 0;
        timer1.Start();
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString(s);
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        timer1.Stop();
        label1.Text = " ";
        MessageBox.Show("Верно!");
        score.Add(GetScoreForLevel());
        this.Close();
        frm1.listBox1.BeginUpdate();
        foreach (string o in players)
        {
            foreach (int j in score)
            {
                frm1.listBox1.Items.Add($"{o} {j}");
            }
        }
        players.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        score.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        
        frm1.listBox1.EndUpdate();
    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        s = s + 1;
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString(s);
    }
    private int GetScoreForLevel()
    {
        return s;
    }
}
```

I need to create a High Score table in my C# WinForms sudoku game and I need that when player click the play button, text from textBox1 adds to the player list and after the player wins, his score (the time for which he won) is added to the score list and then both lists need to be displayed in listBox1.

Comment: I didn't read the whole code, but the first obvious mistake is `frm1 = new Form1(); frm1.frm2 = this;`. remove it. It creates another instance of Form1 which is different from the one that you see (the one that you clicked on its button to open form2).

Comment: @RezaAghaei when I remove these lines (in form1 for example) when I click on the button, I get the error System.NullReferenceException

Comment: @nekzin  your problem is  in score list or listbox1 ?

Comment: @TheOverrider i think problem is in score and player lists because new data don't add in them

Answer (score 0):

Check the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
  public Form2 frm2;
  public Form1 frm1;

  public Form1() {
     InitializeComponent();
  }
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     frm2.players.Add(textBox1.Text);

     textBox1.Text = "";
     frm2.Show();
     this.Hide();
  }
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     frm2 = new Form2();
     frm2.frm1 = this;
  }
```

}

And form 2:

```
public Form1 frm1;
  int s;
  public List<string> players = new List<string>(5);
  public List<int> score = new List<int>(5);

  public Form2() {
     InitializeComponent();
  }
  // New event, not added in the designer
  protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e) { 
     base.OnActivated(e);
     if (!this.timer1.Enabled) {
        this.timer1.Start();
        s = 0;
     }
  }
  private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     //frm1 = new Form1();
     frm1.frm2 = this;
     s = 0;
     timer1.Start();
     label1.Text = Convert.ToString(s);
  }
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

     timer1.Stop();
     label1.Text = " ";
     MessageBox.Show("Верно!");
     score.Add(GetScoreForLevel());
     this.Hide();
     frm1.listBox1.BeginUpdate();
     // No understand the visualization XD
     foreach (string o in players) {
        foreach (int j in score) {
           frm1.listBox1.Items.Add($"{o} {j}");
        }
     }
     players.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
     score.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

     frm1.listBox1.EndUpdate();
     frm1.Show();
  }
  private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     s = s + 1;
     label1.Text = Convert.ToString(s);
  }
  private int GetScoreForLevel() {
     return s;
  }
```

}

Your problem is in Form2_Load because you create a new instance of Form1 and when you re-Show the form you don't show previous one! I have implemented the new event when form is activated, in this way I restart the timer.